# Foreach only return first value

Tags: laravel, foreach

Not sure why it is not getting all the value
In my view

```
<?php $sum_selfmark =0?>
  @foreach
      ($criteria_criteriamarks as $criteria_criteriamark)

      SelfMark:{{$criteria_criteriamark->selfmark}}
      <?php $sum_selfmark+= $criteria_criteriamark->selfmark ?>

  @endforeach
      <p>Total:{{$sum_selfmark}}</p>
```

In my controller

```
 public function go_to_self_marking($id){
    $criteria=Criteria::find($id);
    $criteria_criteriamarks =$criteria->criteriamarks;
    return view('criterias/self-marking')
    ->with('criteria_criteriamarks',$criteria_criteriamarks);
    }
```

Comment: it's because you are using `find`. The `find` method only returns 1 row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to for each a 1 row. Because `$criteria=Criteria::find($id);` returns only 1 row.

If you want to for each then use `$criteria=Criteria::all();` It will return all the row in your Criterias Table.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, did you try to die and dump (dd) the $criteria->criteriamarks? So that we can check what's going on with your loop.

Seems like the @foreach loop has no issue.